# timecop.travel test returns false instead of true - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-test, timecop

I am writing a unit test to check whether 24 hours have passed. If 24 hours have passed then it should return true

here is my attempt

```
test   "messenger tag is more than 24 hours" do
        
        Timecop.travel 2.days.ago
        account = accounts(:messenger_v2)
        contact_d = Contact.create! account: account, name: 'Mr Right', phone_number: nil, external_id: '155581474881005', contact_type: 'MessengerV2', source: 'Inbound', is_registered: true, primary_contact: true
        conversation = Conversation.create! contact: contact_d, account: account, status: 'Open', unread: true, conversation_type: 'Private'
        Message.create! contact: contact_d, message_type: 'Text', text: 'I have some enquries', direction: 'IN', account: account, conversation: conversation, external_id: "in_a#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}"
        msg = conversation.messages.incoming
        time_created = msg.last.created_at
        messenger_tags = time_created < 24.hours.ago
        assert_equal true, messenger_tags
            
    end
```

when I run the test here is the output

```
test_messenger_tag_is_more_than_24_hours                        FAIL (0.14s)
        Expected: true
          Actual: false
        test/models/message_test.rb:175:in `block in <class:MessageTest>'
```

kindly assist

Comment: Does `conversation.messages.incoming` create a new message? Can you possibly share the code for that?

Comment: @Anuj I have added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `turn off Timecop` using `Timecop.return`once the message is created.

```
test "messenger tag is more than 24 hours" do
    Timecop.travel 2.days.ago
    account = accounts(:messenger_v2)
    contact_d = Contact.create! account: account, name: 'Mr Right', phone_number: nil, external_id: '155581474881005', contact_type: 'MessengerV2', source: 'Inbound', is_registered: true, primary_contact: true
    conversation = Conversation.create! contact: contact_d, account: account, status: 'Open', unread: true, conversation_type: 'Private'
    Message.create! contact: contact_d, message_type: 'Text', text: 'I have some enquries', direction: 'IN', account: account, conversation: conversation, external_id: "in_a#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}"
    Timecop.return
    msg = conversation.messages.incoming
    time_created = msg.last.created_at
    messenger_tags = time_created < 24.hours.ago
    assert_equal true, messenger_tags
end
```

---

**Update**
Or you can block to `Timecop.travel`, to avoid calling `Timecop.return` mentioned by @Stefan in the below comment

```
test "messenger tag is more than 24 hours" do
    Timecop.travel 2.days.ago do
        account = accounts(:messenger_v2)
        contact_d = Contact.create! account: account, name: 'Mr Right', phone_number: nil, external_id: '155581474881005', contact_type: 'MessengerV2', source: 'Inbound', is_registered: true, primary_contact: true
        conversation = Conversation.create! contact: contact_d, account: account, status: 'Open', unread: true, conversation_type: 'Private'
        Message.create! contact: contact_d, message_type: 'Text', text: 'I have some enquries', direction: 'IN', account: account, conversation: conversation, external_id: "in_a#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}"
        msg = conversation.messages.incoming
        @time_created = msg.last.created_at
    end
    messenger_tags = @time_created < 24.hours.ago
    assert_equal true, messenger_tags
end
```

Comment: `Timecop.travel` also accepts a block that returns to current time automatically.

Comment: Yes @Stefan I have included your suggestion in answer. Thank you :)

Comment: adding the block causes errors ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `conversation' for #<MessageTest:0x0000558e2daa43b0>``` @SampatBadhe

Comment: ooops my bad. it is due to scope of variable. I've updated the answer, could you please take a look now.